# How to connect to ssh service in the background

Tags: python, ssh

So I want to connect to serveo via this command

```py
os.system("ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -R test:80:127.0.0.1:80 serveo.net > data.txt 2> /dev/null &")
```

Now, it works as I want it to without getting any output and I can keep with the rest of the program, But this command works only on linux becuase of the "/dev/null"  part and I need it to work on Windows too.
Windows doesn't have a "/dev/null" folder where I can throw my output to.

So is there any replacement for that?
It has to be with os.system.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing *2> /dev/null &* with *> NUL 2>&1*

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/777198/equivalent-of-foo-dev-null-in-windows-shell

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer, I tired doing that but the problem is it wont let me continue with the rest of the program..it just getting stuck, for example what I tired to do: ```import os 

def serveo():
 os.system("ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -R asdw:80:127.0.0.1:80 serveo.net > link.txt 2> NUL 2>&1")

def good():
 print("succses")

serveo()
good()```

Comment: Not sure what could be preventing this from running on Windows.
Are there any associated errors? Could it be a permissions issue? Try running as admin

Comment: It doesn't give me any errors, just creates the link.txt file puts there the content and thats it, the problem is that it doesnt continue to the rest of the program and doesnt print "succses". also tried runing as an admin and it gives me the same result

Comment: [I found out that](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29277/print-output-not-shown-when-run-python-script-cron):  A cron job is not started from a terminal so is not attached to a keyboard or screen.

Try sending your print message to a log file.